# How to change the default words on a wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress website ([www.handmadehomes.co.in](http://www.handmadehomes.co.in)) its a hotel booking website. But I want to change some default words on my website like on >>( http://handmadehomes.co.in/your-search-result/ ) there is a heading **"3 hotels found"** I want to that into **"3 properties found"**.

Guide me on how I can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a translation file to rename all the text strings across the wordpress site. There are plugins that help you build the file efficiently like the below:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/